# If $p^2 - q^2$ is a perfect square where $p$ and $q$ are primes $> 5000$ then is one of its prime factors always greater than $17$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Is it true that if $p^2 - q^2$ is a perfect square where $p$ and $q$ are primes $> 5000$ then it has a prime factor greater than $17$?

Note: [This question was asked in MSE but did not receive an answer. Hence posting in MO](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482737/does-every-solution-of-x2-y2-z2-where-y-and-z-are-primes-5000-h).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: looking at MSE post, this appears to be a conjecture. This has to be spelled out, IMHO.

Comment: This is not an answer, but just an observation. If $p^2-q^2=a^2$, then $(a,q,p)$ form a Pythagorean triple. It follows that there are $c$ and $d$ such that $p=c^2+d^2$; $a=2cd$ and $q=c^2-d^2$.  Since $q$ is supposed to be prime, $c-d$ must be 1, so $c=(q+1)/2$ and $d=(q-1)/2$. It follows that $p=(q^2+1)/2$ and $a=(q^2-1)/2$. Hence you’re asking that if $q$ is prime over 5000 and is such that $(q^2+1)/2$ is prime, must one of $q-1$ and $q+1$ have a factor greater than 17.

Comment: This seems very likely: there are something like $n^7$ numbers up to $e^n$ with all factors 17 or less, so it seems likely that there will only be finitely many pairs of such numbers differing by 2.

Comment: Definitely there are finitely many such numbers: if $q-1$ and $q+1$ are 17-smooth, they may be written as $ax^3$ and $by^3$ for certain $a,b$ taken from a finite set, and $y/x$ would be too good rational approximation of $(a/b)^{1/3}$. Instead of Roth theorem you could you Faltings or something else.

Comment: The title asks whether *all* the prime factors exceed $17$, but the body asks whether *one* prime factor exceeds $17$. Please edit for consistency.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for spotting the typpo. Fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is now attracting useful answers on MSE which in my view is a more fitting place for recreational number theory

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks. Can you please fix the typpo for readability?

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha : I thought I had deleted the comment, I have now, because I found that the observation was made by someone else on MSE.